# NameError: name 'rubberBand' is not defined

Tags: kubuntu, python, 20.10

I am using Kubuntu 20.10 + python 3.8.5. I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'rubberBand' is not defined
```

I followed this guide:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899103/python-3-6-how-to-install-rubberband in order to install rubberband without any success!! Has anyone succeed in installing it, somehow?

update (08/07/2021): I used the following solutions without achieving something:

1. sudo pip3 install pyrubberband
2. sudo pip3 install rubberband-cli
3. a) sudo apt update
   b) sudo apt-get install libsndfile-dev
   c) sudo apt-get install librubberband-dev
   d) sudo python 3 -m pip install numpy (required for rubberband)
4. sudo pip3 install rubberband
5. a) python3 -m pip download rubberband and unpack tar.gz file.
   b) edit rubberband-1.0.2/src/numpy.cpp - add #include 
   at the top of the file.
   c) cd rubberband-1.0.2 and then run python3 -m pip install . (or
   whatever python version you're using)

Any better idea? Or why do I get the previously mentioned message?

Comment: "It does not work" is too vague to offer useful advice. You linked to a thread with several possible sequences of steps. It's unclear what you did to get the error. You can fix all of that by editing your question.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: I have updated the question! Thanks!